# Change content of title tag, when switching to other open tab in the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I just recently saw this on two different websites, does anyone know how it is done?
If you have multiple tabs open, and you leave the current one, the title in the tab is changed. Very nice trick!

http://blog.invisionapp.com/

http://zerosixthree.se/create-a-responsive-header-video-with-graceful-degradation/

Comment: If you look at the JS on the second site and search for the string "I miss you" (i.e., the alternate title text) you'll see it is set by a function `ChangePageTitle()`, and if you search for that function you'll see the relevant code.

Comment: Your "question" does not contain any question and will probably be closed.  You must actually ask a specific and well defined question.

Comment: @JK. - The OP's first sentence does end with a question mark... The question could  certainly be phrased more clearly, but nevertheless it is quite obvious what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 9):

This works by registering Handlers on the `onfocus` and `onblur` events of `window`.

jQuery-Style:

```
$(window).on('blur', function() { ... });
```

Without jQuery:

```
window.onblur = function() { ... }
```

If that was not clear: the pages title can be read/written via `document.title`

Comment: That's not how the zerosixthree.se site referenced above does it.

Comment: I actually set up a test file that was supposed to do it that way instead of digging up their code and it worked at least in FF 29, so i posted it

Comment: the blur event is fired when an input get focus for example (in chrome) so that's not working well

Answer (score 6):

```
$(function() {
  var message = "Don't forget us";
  var original;

  $(window).focus(function() {
    if (original) {
      document.title = original;
    }
  }).blur(function() {
    var title = $('title').text();
    if (title != message) {
      original = title;
    }
    document.title = message;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Originally Coded by: https://flintobox.com/blog/

```js
  $(function () {
    var message = "Hey, come back!";
    var original;

    $(window).focus(function() {
      if(original) {
        document.title = original;
      }
    }).blur(function() {
      var title = $('title').text();
      if(title != message) {
        original = title;
      }
      document.title = message;
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $(function () {
    var message = "Hey, come back!";
    var original;

    $(window).focus(function() {
      if(original) {
        document.title = original;
      }
    }).blur(function() {
      var title = $('title').text();
      if(title != message) {
        original = title;
      }
      document.title = message;
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).