# Change title of a webpage if user selects another tab

Tags: html

I am working on a simple html page that should switch the title (`<title>` html tag) to another title... Do you have any ideas how i can do that?

Current title: tanning lounge 
Title that should occur if user selects another tab: Hey please come back (just an example)

I'm not sure if changing the title will create less searching results in google ... does it make a difference?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change content of title tag, when switching to other open tab in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23878277/change-content-of-title-tag-when-switching-to-other-open-tab-in-the-browser)

Answer (score -1):

You can use vanilla javascript to do so..

for example -

```
<li id = "id-1">Tanning lounge</li>
<li id = "id-2" onClick=" myFunction()">Travel Lounge</li>

<script>
function myFunction() {
 document.getElementById("id-1").innerHTML = "Hey please come back";
}
</script>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question asked